# What is the difference $scope.$parent vs $broadcast?

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-scope, broadcast, prototypal-inheritance

What is the difference between `$scope.$parent` and `$broadcast`?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is different. They're not related at all. Two completely different things - not even the same JavaScript type.

`$scope.$parent` is a reference to the parent scope object, while `$broadcast` is a function to broadcast an event.

Comment: To be clear
I have two controllers nested.
Controller A(parent)
Controller B(child)

<div ng-controller="ctrlA">
<input type="button" ng-click="buttonevent()">
   <div ng-controller="ctrlB">
     {{name}}
   </div>
</div>
-----script------

CtrlB{
$scope.$parent.buttonevent=function(){
$scope.name="AngularJs"
  }
}

Is the above scenario possible?

Comment: To be clear
I have two controllers nested.
Controller A(parent)
Controller B(child)

<div ng-controller="ctrlA">
<input type="button" ng-click="buttonevent()">
   <div ng-controller="ctrlB">
     {{name}}
   </div>
</div>
-----script------

CtrlB{
$scope.$parent.buttonevent=function(){
$scope.name="AngularJs"
  }
}

Is the above scenario possible?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. I would recommend against it though, since child components/controllers shouldn't depend in any way on their parent. The above causes tight coupling with the parent, making reuse of the child difficult. For instance, in your example, the child controller has to know that the parent has a function called `buttonevent`. That's undesireable.

Comment: Then what is the solution to achieve this kind of scenario?

Comment: Take a look at angular components and the concept of one-way binding. That ought to guide you to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically im writing a common layout.
Inside common layout developer will write his code using ui-view.The common layout will have button events when fired it should change the state of ui-view which is nested.

For this if i use components i think i cant achieve because

Top-framwrok(buttons,titles e.t.c)
Body-developer-this part is an ui-view
Bottom-framwork(border ending and some styles)

So for framwork i will have controller 
So when firing any change in framework should trigger developer template also.